# CakePHP error with a program to make an array

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I make a program to create an array with the range of my hero :

```
public function surface($fighterId,$porte_max,$porte_min){

    $porte = $porte_max;
    $longeur = 0;
    $surface;
    $i =0;
    $coordonne_x=$this->findById($fighterId, array('field'=>'coordinate_x'));
    $coordonne_y=$this->findById($fighterId, array('field'=>'coordinate_y'));

    for( $for = ($coordonne_y['Fighter']['coordinate_y'] - $porte) ; ($coordonne_y['Fighter']['coordinate_y'] + $porte) ; $for++)
    {
        for( $for2 = ( $coordonne_x['Fighter']['coordinate_x'] - $longeur) ; ($coordonne_x['Fighter']['coordinate_x'] + $longeur) ; $for2++)
        {

            $surface[$i] = '[' . $for . '|' . $for2  . ']';
            $i++;
        }
        if ($longeur < $porte)
        {
            $longeur++ ;
        }
        else $longeur-- ;    
    }
    return $surface;
}
```

I don't understand the error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)     in /var/www/html/WebArenaGroupSI4-02-AF/app/Model/Fighter.php on line 36

Comment: your `for` loops are endless..

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue with PHP memory has been exhausted. You can change your PHP `memory limit` in php.ini. Then restart your server.

Also your code has an endless for, the correct syntax for a for statement is like the following

```
for(initializationvalue , conditions, updatevalue){
   // do your thing here
}
```

But in your condition, you did not put any conditions but instead did calculation in that.